# "AttributeError: module 'robin_stocks' has no attribute 'login'"

Tags: python

```
import robin_stocks as r

r.login(config.username, config.password)
```

I wrote a script in Atom using the `robin_stocks` module, and it runs with no error on my Mac, however when I transferred the code over to a Google Cloud VM, the error `AttributeError: module 'robin_stocks' has no attribute 'login'` arose.

I know that the module does have this attribute, since I've been able to run it in Atom (and have used the `hasattr()` function to confirm that the attribute exists), as well as the fact that https://robin-stocks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html states that `login()` is an attribute.

I understand there have been similar questions asked on here about modules not having attributes, but none of the solutions I have seen have helped me resolve this issue.

Please bear with me, this is my first post.

Comment: The usual explanations for something like this are that you've installed an entirely different version of the module, or that you've named your script the same thing as the module.  Try `print(r.__file__)` and `print(dir(r))` to see exactly where it is coming from, and what's actually in it.

Comment: @John LaCava Did you ever figure this one out? I've been trying to solve this for the last few days. I did the print out and I don't think there is a conflict. The API changed a bit where I thing you have to use "authentication" but that and "login" are not working for me.

Comment: @hefty_kat I solved it a while ago, don’t quite remember but I think I had some directory or file that was named robin_stocks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing
"import robin_stocks as r"
to
"import robin_stocks.robinhood as r"